# Finding a value in an array by type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to build a method for finding items in an array by type. Consider this particular setup:

```js
abstract class Animal {}

class Dog extends Animal {}
class Cat extends Animal {}
class Horse extends Animal {}

const animals: Animal[] = [new Dog, new Cat, new Horse];
```

I'm trying to write a function that can find an element from `animals` by its type, something like: `findAnimal<Dog>(animals)`. In plain English: "find the first element of `animals` that is an instance of `Dog`." Here's a rough sketch of that:

```js
function find<A extends Animal>(items: Animal[]): A {
    return items.find((a: Animal) => a instanceof A) as A;
}
```

This doesn't compile, and I understand why: that generic argument no longer exists after compilation. However, is there a way to get something like this to work? I'm certainly okay with modifying the function to take two parameters:

```
function find(items: Animal[], A: NOT_SURE_WHAT_GOES_HERE): WHAT_TO_RETURN {
  // ...
}
```

However, with this change I'm not sure how to properly specify that second argument or return type. What are my options?

Comment: You'd have to pass the class as a parameter, not a generic; `find(animals, Dog)`, its type would be `typeof Animal`.

Comment: But how would you specify the return type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the generic in both the type of the class argument and the return value as follows:

```js
function find<A extends Animal>(animals: Animal[], cls: new() => A): A | undefined {
    return animals.find((value): value is A => value instanceof cls);
}
```

Note that, by using a [*type predicate*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) as the return value from the `find` callback, we don't need a type assertion any more. This is much safer - you *might not* find a `cls` instance in `animals`, you're potentially returning `undefined as A` in your current implementation.

The generic can be inferred from the second argument when you call this:

```js
find(animals, Dog);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgggOwJYFthkEBvAXwCgKU0MARAewHMEBTADwlewBMMcCRUpRroEAYWCIOXXvzyFi5aqjEAJBlDCs2nbnywKhyigDMArtni4G2BKdy8APJl2yDAxQD4AFMCPIYABchoLIANoAugA0SIEh2KwA7j4AlAgAvF5YqSGuAD4IljysDok8pBQICFCsEOZQdv5hYAB0ZTw+PgBuROasuQi9yP0IuPyZ2cOjjpD+sKwMpnFgqQDcFJTUtpAIPCGMLIXFpY6sFRn2jp1RsYepFEA)

Comment: This did the trick! However, for future readers: If `Dog` takes constructor arguments you'll need to clarify a tad: `cls: new(...args: any[]) => A` to get that to work. Otherwise the compiler will fail with something like the cryptic message here: "typeof Dog is not assignable to new() => Dog"

Comment: @ChipBell yes, the construct signature has to match whatever is actually being constructed, you basically rearrange the call `new Thing(arg1, arg2)` to the signature `new(arg1: Type1, arg2: Type2) => Thing`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of making an entirely new function, you can create a search predicate hat is also [a type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types). This way you can call the vanilla `Array#find` method but you also ensure you get the correct type back:

```
abstract class Animal {}

class Dog extends Animal { bark() {} }
class Cat extends Animal { meow() {} }
class Horse extends Animal { neigh() {}}

const animals: Animal[] = [new Dog, new Cat, new Horse];

const animal = animals.find((item: Animal): item is Dog => item instanceof Dog);

if (animal) { //make sure it's not `undefined`
  animal.meow();  //Error - it's not a Cat
  animal.neigh(); //Error - it's not a Horse
  animal.bark();  //OK - it's a Dog
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgggOwJYFthkEBvAXwFgAoalNDAEQHsBzBAUwA8J3sATDDgJFSCEMCgBrABQBKUmQSUqddAgDCwRFx79BeQsRIJ87JgHc5CpbVRqAEkyhh2HbrwFYDI49na4WAAsrcmVaJmxIBGBvZDAALi9hZABtAF0EAF4EFL9zBGYWABoEPI0tErLHZ3Y0gG5qcMjEGOSs6NiwADoAM1x+aWlcHnxEoUNZROH2fARcRlYsgD45kbnmmNgzHoLWWQaaKlwd6VaJ0QB6C8JJVzAAVyhXYYByDGwmRAADe-52Pr8fC+1AQHWSXVMFjkdVBVwAolAoE4EABaVZvUqfaLlCAgsGGLp+ALBfYIeGI5Fo17vLHABDVFx4s5ELriKTQ2EXADyAGlUeiMHTCtQyEA)

This can then be generalised and made easily reusable as a curried function:

```
abstract class Animal {}

class Dog extends Animal { bark() {} }
class Cat extends Animal { meow() {} }
class Horse extends Animal { neigh() {}}

const animals: Animal[] = [new Dog, new Cat, new Horse];

const search = <A extends Animal>(species: new() => A) => (item: Animal): item is A =>
  item instanceof species;

const animal = animals.find(search(Dog));

if (animal) { //make sure it's not `undefined`
  animal.meow();  //Error - it's not a Cat
  animal.neigh(); //Error - it's not a Horse
  animal.bark();  //OK - it's a Dog
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=18&pc=2#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgggOwJYFthkEBvAXwFgAoalNDAEQHsBzBAUwA8J3sATDDgJFSCEMCgBrABQBKUmQSUqddAgDCwRFx79BeQsRIJ87JgHc5CpbVRqAEkyhh2HbrwFYDI49na4WAAsrcmVaJmxIBGBvZDAALi9hZABtAF0EAF4EFL9zBGYWABoEPI0tErLHZ3Y0gG5qcMjEFwlYQKyEAB5MN11PIUMAPmkwAAd2WFx2BNL2S3lMoaxF5elcHnxEwaJZRI32fARcQSyh6gRjzePmmNgzADMEccnpsAaaFQiomOTO38MYAAdA9cPxRuw2sFCrJZB9qLgntIAbtRAB6NGESSuMAAVygrg2AHIMNgmIgAAa4-jsUF+PgUi7RWJA0wWOR1S4YgCiUCgTgQAForiTSuTouUIEyUcggX4AsE4QgeXyBcLiaTxcAENUXNKWeIpByuWiAPIAaSFIow2sK1DIQA)

Since this is still a predicate, we can re-use it for any of the default array methods that take one

```
const dogs = animals.filter(search(Dog)); //=> Dog[]
dogs.forEach(dog => dog.bark()); //OK

if (animals.every(search(Dog))) {
  animals.forEach(dog => dog.bark()); //OK
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgggOwJYFthkEBvAXwFgAoalNDAEQHsBzBAUwA8J3sATDDgJFSCEMCgBrABQBKUmQSUqddAgDCwRFx79BeQsRIJ87JgHc5CpbVRqAEkyhh2HbrwFYDI49na4WAAsrcmVaJmxIBGBvZDAALi9hZABtAF0EAF4EFL9zBGYWABoEPI0tErLHZ3Y0gG5qcMjEFwlYQKyEAB5MN11PIUMAPmkwAAd2WFx2BNL2S3lMoaxF5elcHnxEwaJZRI32fARcQSyh6gRjzePmmNgzADMEccnpsAaaFQiovlYMbJiyTAADoHrhkDwoKN2G1goVZLIPr8WCCHk4AKJwYLIs4IZHA8RSOSIhAAelJAHkANKNKi4J7SQGGEHsABu7CgAE9obDpPCEaQLtFYqiMVjpDilnjWASJDIEXUyZSaVQyEA)

---

This function can be *further generalised* for any super/subclass relationship and to allow any variadic constructors. Do be aware that your interfaces [should not be empty[https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-all-types-assignable-to-empty-interfaces):

```
abstract class Animal { isPet?: boolean }

class Dog extends Animal { bark() {} }
class Cat extends Animal { constructor(name: string) {super(); } meow() {} }
class Horse extends Animal { constructor(age: number, recehorse: boolean) {super();} neigh() {}}

declare const animals: Animal[];

const search = <Super, Child extends Super>(specific: new(...args: any[]) => Child) => (item: Super): item is Child =>
  item instanceof specific;

const dog = animals.find(search(Dog));     //OK
const cat = animals.find(search(Cat));     //OK
const horse = animals.find(search(Horse)); //OK

const dogs = animals.filter(search(Dog));  //OK

if (animals.every(search(Dog))) { }        //OK

animals.find(search(String)); // Error - String is not assignable to Animal

declare const cats: Cat[];
cats.find(search(Dog)); //Error - Dog is not a assignable to Cat
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgggOwJYFthkEBvBXMABQFMIB+ALgRAHsXlrhsEBfAWABQglGgwARFgHME1AB4Rq2ACYYcBIqWbAoAawAUASlI9ew1OgQBhYIjkLlqvIWJlYLbJCgBXeCyh7sYHxqJk9cbEkjEjAvAAdqfwMAbl4EYJYAd0NjUwERCwAJPzBqGXlFFSwnDVd3Tx8IPz1gSRCEbC98EASAGgQoalhqAAtittZ2TmwomPjEpJNsalxJYeySHn4hASVB1AGkOsQudWQwJjVnAG0AXSTBYSOEEu1YYYQAXgQAHgBlON6VmGuGQSjK9kq-zmAD49GB4rBcAAzXCwJhLLIAOmx2kk5wQXAAnrcjB9oUCQUpSeS9LgFPgmFCEgYmHTqPhyBhLMDQZ9oYIEOR6eQPBAuEMWEjngjkaj7ts3KKkDZPgTqmdMSjlHDOFA3nprBADMlBaaAPRmhAAeQA0o8laMoCVVSdnGBNeElDrXmsik7qMaUhbrXaFU8lFIXer3VqvS89WsJJETaaEMHbYJkQg9BHIqQBQhc5iQNp9MlBFt7ZBC1IMF9XUQYyCFP54-qk4HBLmY34AKJwNa5vk1yTF0uGE0WjPbLPNaOY6gANwShO9Cb0HeN+YEgobGqRfYHOcjZJHY90E6DZunlYEe6b2rba1+0HCyavCF7UCgfgQAFoEBfKA305doWGOdAVkCEAOAQRoqlOB4dj2bRSkVatYBsfFDVueVMIgB8411dspEDNMzS-H8oH-BAk1A7BwIJZ4vBAfIMElKwbCAA)

However, be aware that the generic type inference only works as long as the second function is given a type. The example above doesn't need to explicitly supply the generic arguments because we call with the first parameter `Dog` which sets `Child` and then the second function is passed as an array callback, so it immediately gets `Animal` or `Cat` as a type for `Super`. However, doing this:

```
const searchDog = search(Dog);
```

does not set the `Super` generic argument and thus it gets set to `unknown`. If you want to derive a predicate and set the types, you need

```
const searchDog = search<Animal, Dog>(Dog);
```